# Minimum value of named array, return array name

Tags: javascript, arrays, min

The array looks like this:

```js
arr[0] = "value";
arr[1] = "value2";
```

or it can be something like this:

```js
var items = {
  "dioxanes"     :  0,
  "shunning"     :  1,
  "plowed"       :  2,
  "hoodlumism"   :  3,
  "cull"         :  4,
  "learnings"    :  5,
  "transmutes"   :  6,
  "cornels"      :  7,
  "undergrowths" :  8,
  "hobble"       :  9,
  "peplumed"     : 10,
  "fluffily"     : 11,
  "leadoff"      : 12,
  "dilemmas"     : 13,
  "firers"       : 14,
  "farmworks"    : 15,
  "anterior"     : 16,
  "flagpole"     : 17
};
```

Now the values here will be percents and that must be compared, but the returned value should be the name of minimum value array object.

The values, as you understand, can have 2 or more with the same item.

Comment: var items = {"dioxanes": 0, "shunning": 1,...... is not an array.

Comment: ... it is an object declared via [Object Literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers)

Comment: What should be returned if there are you names with the lowest value?

Answer (score 0):

`items` is not array, it's an object.

```
var items = {"dioxanes": 0,  "shunning": 1,  "plowed": 2,
            "hoodlumism": 3, "cull": 4,      "learnings": 5,
            "transmutes": 6, "cornels": 7,   "undergrowths": 8,
            "hobble": 9,     "peplumed": 10, "fluffily": 11,
            "leadoff": 12,   "dilemmas": 13, "firers": 14,
            "farmworks": 15, "anterior": 16, "flagpole": 17};

var min = null, key_min, key;

for (key in items) {
  if (items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     if (min === null || items[key] < min) {
         min = items[key];
　　　　　key_min = key;
     }
  }
}

console.log("The key holds min value is: " + key_min);
```

Comment: the way how data is presented is not so important, eather object eather array. important is name > value combination and variations. there are 16 names with values that im working with. i can get names and add percentage values to them but the function with min value and return of the name of that value was the biggest headache of it. if it will return more then 2 names then it will select only the first one. doesnt matter witch:) on next check there wont be more names with same value, only less :) to split values and select only the first one part i can do ;)